# Refresh User Layout from Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, salespath

I have an issue where we have fields that a user may need to modify, but when they do we need the quote to be invalidated. I have developed a trigger for this purpose that uses metadata for the tracked fields.

When they modify the fields on the opp, the trigger fires and then moves the opp stage back to it's initial stage, however, the opportunity is not displayed with the new stage unless they **refresh** the page. I would like to make sure that the opportunity displays the new stage name after the trigger is done firing, **without a user having to refresh**.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks for your help.

Thanks,

Comment: are you using the standard page or custom?

Comment: We are using a standard page. I believe....let me check.

Comment: It's a standard record page.

Comment: It should auto refresh once the save button is clicked. Are you doing the update in any async methods?

Comment: I have a future method that is called on quote from the Apex Trigger for Opportunities but I don't do any async updates on the opportunity.

Comment: where is your stage update happening? trigger or future method?

Comment: It's happening in the trigger in Before Update

Comment: Never Mind, I stand corrected. I'm running the update from the Future Method.

Comment: Basically I use the Future Method to unsync the Quote from the Opportunity by setting the SyncedQuoteId to Null and then Updating the Opportunity.

Comment: I might be able to fix it with Process Builder...

Comment: AFAIK, you can not refresh your STANDARD detail page. You will need to move your code in async transaction or think of a custom page implementation

Comment: Any async update will work like trigger, workflow, process builder.

Comment: AFAIK? I might be able to unsync from the quote side rather than from the opportunity side.

Comment: `AFAIK - As far as i know`.If your opportunity status logic is not dependent on quote logic, then you can update the opportunity in trigger and then call the future method. But if both the logic are dependent.. meaning, if any thing fails, there should be a roll back, then you need to write the whole logic in one place. I recommend using  Process Builder. You can access child records in PB and this is OOTB feature.

Comment: Can you unsync Quotes from Process Builder. Currently attempting to do so, but it is not unsyncing the opp.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using salesforce console then you can easily achieve this using salesforce push notifications:

Trailhead module below covers the concept in detail:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/service_console_customize/service_console_customize_push

This is not yet available on lightning:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lJYEQA2

one alternative to refresh the lightning page is

1. In your trigger create a Custom Notifications with Platform Events https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_streaming
2. Create a sample component which would subscribe to the event
   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation